# Devise 'user_signed_in?' not accessible from CanCan 'Ability' model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, cancan

I'm working on a Rails app and have Devise set up and working with all the default settings, and am setting up CanCan.

The following is the content of the 'Ability' class, (not really my code, based on several tutorials);

```
class Ability
  include CanCan::Ability

  def initialize(user)
    user ||= User.new # guest user (not logged in)
    if user_signed_in?
        can :manage, :all
    end
  end
end
```

I know the file itself works, as I've added a sample `authorize! :edit, @document` to one of my controllers. If I remove the `if user_signed_in?` line (and, of course, the `end`), then when the `can :manage, :all` line is present, I can access the `document` controller's actions, and without it, it says 'Access Denied'.

However when I attempt to do this with the `user_signed_in?` line present, I get the following error;

> NoMethodError in DocumentsController#edit
>
> undefined method `user_signed_in?' for #

And, interestingly, `user_signed_in?` works perfectly in my views, where I display a login box or the details of the currently logged in user with an `if` ... `else` block.

Any ideas how I can access `user_signed_in?` here? In the longer term, I intend to read a value from the user's record to identify their access level, but it's important that the concept works, as the variables will be coming from the same place!

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure exactly what you're trying to do but you can include `Devise::Controllers::Helpers` to the `Ability` class and then replace  `user_signed_in?` with `signed_in?(:user)`.